# How to convert a file object to a plain object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

I need to convert a file object from an input to a plain object to upload it to firestore using react:

```
await setDoc(doc(db, "users", userId, "images", file.name), file)
```

But get this error:

> FirebaseError: Function setDoc() called with invalid data. Data must
> be an object, but it was: a custom File object

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To upload a File object directly to Firestore, but Firestore expects the data to be in the form of a plain JavaScript object. To achieve this, you need to convert the File object into a format that Firestore can handle, such as converting it to a Blob or a base64-encoded string.

```
import { doc, setDoc } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { getDownloadURL, ref, uploadString } from 'firebase/storage';
import { db, storage } from './firebase'; // Your Firebase configuration

async function uploadFileToFirestore(file, userId) {
  const reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onload = async (event) => {
    const base64Data = event.target.result.split(',')[1]; // Extract base64 data from Data URL

    try {
      // Upload the base64 data to Firebase Storage
      const storageRef = ref(storage, `users/${userId}/images/${file.name}`);
      await uploadString(storageRef, base64Data, 'base64');

      // Get the download URL from Storage
      const downloadURL = await getDownloadURL(storageRef);

      // Create a plain object with the download URL
      const imageData = {
        name: file.name,
        url: downloadURL,
      };

      // Upload the object to Firestore
      await setDoc(doc(db, 'users', userId, 'images', file.name), imageData);

      console.log('File uploaded successfully!');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error uploading file:', error);
    }
  };

  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```